# IIS - "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am building an asp.net web application which has been working on local and staging. however, when i deployed to live, there is a little weird issue occurred. below is the live environment details.

live environment:

- Server 2003
- IIS 6

when the request url is below, if page not found, it will redirect to page 404 configured in the IIS.
"http://www.xxxx.com/folder1/default.aspx"

however, when the request url is below (with a dot in the folder), it will show a IIS default 404 message which is "The system cannot find the file specified." which isn't what i configured in the IIS and it seems like it skips all the http handlers and modules. Therefore, my custom http handler stop working with this kind of url.

"http://www.xxxx.com/folder.1/default.aspx"

My guess it something to do with the IIS setting. i have have several research, there is no other issue like me.

appreciated if anyone can help. Thanks a lot.

Dion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible reason could be tool such as [UrlScan](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/726/urlscan-overview/) - you need to explicitly configured it to allow dot(.)s in the url - this can be done by editing `<Windows Folder>\system32\inetsrv\urlscan.ini` and setting `AllowDotInPath=1`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick response. I did see the UrlScan installed in our live server. i did according to your instruction. however, the IIS responses the same. should i restart IIS? as it is a live environment. it might not be appropriated to do so.

Comment: just did a quick research that in order to let changes take effect. it requires the command IISRESET in the server - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326444

Thanks so much for the help!